# Spacy CLI falling on windows

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, spacy

I've tried to run an exemplary Spacy project via CLI on Windows (following [these instructions](https://spacy.io/usage/projects#run)). The project instructions are saved in .yml format, by declaring the steps that need to be done. Unfortunately, running for example

```
python -m spacy project run preprocess
```

where `preprocess` step contains calls to `mkdir` and `mv` commands, fails with

> Can not execute command (..). Do you have 'mkdir' installed?

And it's not due to parameter differences between `mkdir` in unix and Windows (I've modified .yml accordingly) - I can run them directly in the command line. The question is: I'm missing something obvious or the Spacy's CLI is only written for the unix machines?
I'm working on Windows 10, the same behavior in cmd and build-in PowerShell.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a known issue, see: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/6957

Comment: Thanks! I've looked at the issues yesterday, but I must have missed it.